# Cannot read properties in useEffect function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Below, I am briefing you about the issue, which I have been facing for a while now. I have been running a react project, which is inbuilt on React. Being new to React ecosystem, I am not able to figure it how to resolve this.

We have a file named Home.js

```html
import { useEffect } from 'react';

import bg from '../../images/bg.webp';

import * as uiService from '../../services/ui';

const Home = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    window.onload = function () {
      uiService.showDarkHeader();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="home">
      <img src={bg} alt="bg" />
      <div className="home__title">
        <h1>Could not find the place to go?</h1>
        <h1>Great!</h1>
        <div className="home__button-container">
          <button>Quick Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

export default Home;
```

And another file is named ui.js in which we are configuring all the functions of js.

```html
export const alert = message => {
  window.alert(message);
};

export const showLoading = () => {
  const loading = document.getElementById("loading");
  loading.classList.remove("hidden");
  loading.classList.add('shown');
};

export const hideLoading = () => {
  const loading = document.getElementById("loading");
  loading.classList.remove("shown");
  loading.classList.add("hidden");
};

export const showDarkHeader = () => {
  const header = document.getElementById("header");
  const headerLeft = document.getElementById("header-left");
  const headerRight = document.getElementById("header-right");
  const headerMiddle = document.getElementById("header-middle");
  const headerMiddleItems = document.getElementsByClassName("header__middle-item");
  const headerActions = document.getElementsByClassName("header__action");

  const search = document.getElementById("search");
  const searchContainer = document.getElementById("search-container");

  header.classList.remove("header--light");
  headerLeft.classList.remove("header__left--light");
  headerRight.classList.remove("header__right--light");
  headerMiddle.classList.remove("header__middle--light");
  for (let i = 0; i < headerMiddleItems.length; i++) {
    headerMiddleItems[i].classList.remove("header__middle-item--light");
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < headerActions.length; i++) {
    headerActions[i].classList.remove("header__action--light");
  }

  search.classList.remove("search--light");
  searchContainer.classList.remove("search__container--light");

  document.body.style.background = "#000";
};

export const showLightHeader = () => {
  const header = document.getElementById("header");
  const headerLeft = document.getElementById("header-left");
  const headerRight = document.getElementById("header-right");
  const headerMiddle = document.getElementById("header-middle");
  const headerMiddleItems = document.getElementsByClassName("header__middle-item");
  const headerActions = document.getElementsByClassName("header__action");

  const search = document.getElementById("search");
  const searchContainer = document.getElementById("search-container");

  header.classList.add("header--light");
  headerLeft.classList.add("header__left--light");
  headerRight.classList.add("header__right--light");
  headerMiddle.classList.add("header__middle--light");
  for (let i = 0; i < headerMiddleItems.length; i++) {
    headerMiddleItems[i].classList.add("header__middle-item--light");
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < headerActions.length; i++) {
    headerActions[i].classList.add("header__action--light");
  }

  search.classList.add("search--light");
  searchContainer.classList.add("search__container--light");

  document.body.style.background = "#fff";
};
```

As you can see in the Home.js we are importing it and rendering it on the download function using useEffect.

But when I am running the npm run start. I am facing an error prompt that states that Cannot read the properties of null.

Shall I need to check the useEffect or what needs to be changed in the code?

Below, I have shared the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
Module.showDarkHeader
C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/airbnb/src/services/ui.js:28
  25 |  const search = document.getElementById("search");
  26 |  const searchContainer = document.getElementById("search-container");
  27 | 
> 28 |  header.classList.remove("header--light");
     | ^  29 |  headerLeft.classList.remove("header__left--light");
  30 |  headerRight.classList.remove("header__right--light");
  31 |  headerMiddle.classList.remove("header__middle--light");
View compiled
window.onload
C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/airbnb/src/components/home/Home.js:11
   8 | 
   9 |  useEffect(() => {
  10 |    window.onload = function () {
> 11 |      uiService.showDarkHeader();
     | ^  12 |    }
  13 |  }, []);
  14 | 
View compiled
```

Thanks, really appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Where in the code is the element with id of `header` ?

Comment: None of those things necessarily exist when you run that code.  You're mixing multiple programming paradigms when you'd be better served choosing one.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the id of "header", which should be here:
`<h1 id="header">Could not find the place to go?</h1>`
In your showDarkMode() function it does not find the header and triggers the "cannot read property of null" error when trying to access header.classList.
Be careful to also put the ids "header-left"... in the right components.

As a side note, I would add that this not really the way this kind of thing is done in React anymore.
Instead of having showDarkMode find and modify the css classes manually, you can use a class that will change at runtime like this:

```
export const showDarkHeader = () => {
const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = React.useState(true);// We store if the website is dark mode in a variable that defaults to true when the page is displayed.
///...
return (
/*...*/
<h1 id="header" className={isDarkMode ? 'header': 'header header--light'}>Could not find the place to go?</h1>
/*...*/
)
///...
}
```

And you can extend it to all your components. This way, React will just update the UI when isDarkMode changes.